# Detect and measure pattern in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I define a pattern as successive rows with different values (ex: abc def ghi)

I'd like to be able to detect a pattern like abc def ghi and count the number of rows that constitute this pattern.

```
DATA PATTERN_COUNT

abc     3
def
ghi     2
abc
ghi   
klm
```

Comment: There is for `abc` output `3` ? Not `2` ?

Comment: 3 is for 3 rows: def ghi abc. 2 is for 2 rows: abc ghi